# sending String from C# to MFC through SendMessage

Tags: c#, mfc, pinvoke

I know how to PInvoke a method that wants a CString by using LPCTSTR instead and setting up the DllImport to call with the LPstr conversion.

However, how would I do it with SendMessage where LPARAM is an IntPtr?

Would this work?

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String lParam);
```

Comment: The simplest solution would be to declare LPARAM as a `String` :-)

Comment: Why not just use [IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx)?

Comment: @CodyGray So create another DllImport method?

Comment: @scottm I suppose I could marshal into native bytes, but I was hoping for the easier UnmanagedType.LPStr

Comment: Yes, you can overload P/Invoke signatures. You're right, there is a way to do it by marshaling, but that's slightly more complicated.

Comment: @Xaade you can always try your example and if it crashes, you know it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# string to long pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094463/c-sharp-string-to-long-pointer)

Comment: Upon closer inspection of your code, I do have to wonder why you're explicitly calling the ANSI version of the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare it simply like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
    IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam);
```

The default marshalling is as an pointer to null-terminated character array. If you really want the ANSI version, then that's the default. And you should use `SetLastError` in case you want to capture the error code in case of failure.

I trust you know that it cannot work if the window is in a different process.

Comment: Quick question, when WndProc gets called, the lParam is always an IntPtr. How do you get the string value out of the lParam?

Comment: `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` or `Marshal.PtrToStringUni`

Comment: Thank you David. I'm using your solution.